# How to map object type field in Nhibernate Auto Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

When trying to map, I got this error:

> Association references unmapped class: System.Object

My class:

```
public partial class MessageIdentifier
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual object Item { get; set; }
}
```

And the convention:

```
public class MyUsertypeConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type.Name == "Object")
        instance.CustomType<string>();
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest how to map?

Answer (score 1):

As a simple *(quick, naive)* solution - I would suggest to create and map real `string` property. And then let your *setter* and *getter* *(or some AOP or listener)* to do the "to/from string conversion":

```
public partial class MessageIdentifier
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual object Item 
    { 
        get { return ... my conversion from string; }
        set { ItemString = ...my conversion to string; } 
    }
    public virtual string ItemString { get; set; }
}
```

A smart and preferred *(but a bit more challenging)* is to create `CustomType` - which will hide that conversion and support REUSE. Check e.g. here

- [NHibernate Pitfalls: Custom Types and Detecting Changes](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-custom-types-and-detecting-changes)
- [Creating and Testing a Custom NHibernate User Type](http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/9293603159/creating-and-testing-a-custom-nhibernate-user-type)

Answer (score 0):

Not a satisfactory answer. It doesn't work with class that is generated from xsd by using XML. You can try the following:

```
public partial class MessageIdentifier
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    private object itemField;
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemField; }
        set { this.itemField = value; }
    }
}
```